# The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'T' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**NOTE**: All of the code here is paraphrased as an example, as I can't show real code.

I have a view model class that looks something like

```
public SearchViewModel
{
   public string Term
   {
     get; set;
   }

   public SearchResult Result
   {
     get; set;
   }

   public List<Filter> Filters
   {
     get; set;
   }
}
```

This is bound to a regular controller and everything works fine:

```
 public ActionResult Search (SearchViewModel model)
 {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           model.Result = _searchService.Search(model.Term);
           return View(model);
      }
 }
```

I also have another action that handles taking in a POST from a form that contains checkboxes. This controller handles creating Filter classes and redirects to the Search action.

Something like:

```
    public ActionResult Filter(FormCollection formParams)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Search", new SearchViewModel
        {
            Term = formParams["Term"],
            Filters = 
                formParams.Keys
                    .Cast<String>()
                    .Where(k => k.Contains("filter"))
                    .Select(k => Filter.Build(k, formParams[k]))
                    .ToList()                        
        });                                        
    }
```

This passes a ViewModel with the List collection populated back to the Search action.

However, in the search action, ModelState.IsValid now returns false. This is because the model binder throws this exception:

> The parameter conversion from type
>   'System.String' to type 'Filter'
>   failed because no type converter can
>   convert between these types.

Looking at the raw value in ModelState for "Filters" shows that is a string:

```
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Filter]
```

It seems like the actual contents of the List is lost during the transition between actions, likely because it only called ToString() on the property members.

At this point, I have a vague idea of why this is failing, and I figure I could write a custom model binder or type converters to make it work, however, I have a feeling that this approach smells, and this is probably something that is trivial, I'm just approaching it wrong.

So, what is the proper ASP.NET MVC 3 to pass a collection of complex types from one action to another?

Comment: Try this (i had the same problem but i don´t remember if this was the solution):
return RedirectToAction("Search", new RouteValueDictionary(
    new SearchViewModel{...});

Answer (score 0):

A RedirectToAction is simply a HTTP 302 redirect. Are you sure you need the browser to re-request a new page?

For instance do you want to avoid a page reload from triggerring a "resubmit post data" dialog? (see POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern)

Why not just use:

```
public ActionResult Filter(FormCollection formParams) 
{
   return Search(new SearchViewModel{
     Term = formParams["Term"], 
     Filters =  
       formParams.Keys 
                .Cast<String>() 
                .Where(k => k.Contains("filter")) 
                .Select(k => Filter.Build(k, formParams[k])) 
                .ToList()                         
    });                                         
}
```

Alternatively you could use TempData to store the state between requests, or possibly client side cookies if suitable.

If you want the Search results page to be bookmarkable in a users browser you'll need to represent the search parameter's state in the URL using REST or some form of serilaised string (eg. JSON)

Answer (score 0):

One of the common reason causing this error is using the some kind of `reserve words` such as *"Action, Comment, Filter, etc."*. So, changing the `Action` name *"Filter"* with another name i.e. *"ApplyFilter"* will probably solve the problem. Hope this helps...