# Asp.net MVC 3 "parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type failed" when using SelectList Dropdown box

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, type-conversion

I'm stuck and after looking this up for hours, I think I need more eyeballs.

The situation is the following:

It's an Asp.Net MVC3 with Entity Framework 4 project. And I have two classes. One ConfigurationFile and another one Action. There is a one-to-many relationship between the two. Here is a simplified view on the code:

```
public class ConfigurationFile
{
    [Key, Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "uniqueidentifier")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "uniqueidentifier")]
    [Required]
    public Guid ActionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Models.Action Action { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    [Key, Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "uniqueidentifier")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ActionValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to create a new ConfigurationFile, and are my two controller methods (and at this point, this is 95% Visual Studio 10 generated code):

```
// db is my context class.
//
// GET: /Configuration/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ActionId = new SelectList(db.Actions, "Id", "ActionValue");
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Configuration/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.ConfigurationFile configurationfile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        configurationfile.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        db.ConfigurationFiles.Add(configurationfile);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ActionId = new SelectList(db.Actions, "Id", "ActionValue", configurationfile.ActionId);
    return View(configurationfile);
}
```

And here is a snippet of my Create view:

```
@model MyProject.Areas.ConfigurationFile.Models.ConfigurationFile

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Configuration File</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActionId, "Action")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ActionId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActionId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I open the Create page, I can clearly see that my dropdown for the Action class is fine (correct value -- the Action.Id -- and text -- Action.ActionValue -- ) but when I submit the form, I have the following error: "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MyProject.Models.Action' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

Help please !!

Comment: For info, I've already looked any many other questions related to the same issue here on SO. But none of the answers could solve my problem )c:

Comment: I encountered a similar error due to using a `reserve word`. So, if the problem is caused from a similar issue, you might have a look at my answer on [The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'T' failed because no type converter can convert between these types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406094/the-parameter-conversion-from-type-system-string-to-type-t-failed-because-no/35025214#35025214). Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

Right now MVC has no way of connecting your dropdownlist from your view to the ActionId of your ConfigurationFile object.

I would try replacing this line:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ActionId", String.Empty)
```

for this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActionId, ViewBag.ActionId)
```

Other than that, I can't think of what else you might have done wrong.
I hope that helps!

Comment: I did the exact same think for other models and MVC could make the assocation for those.

Also, it didn't work, could even compile: 

"'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<...Models.ConfigurationFile>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.  <...>\Areas\ConfigurationFile\Views\Configuration\Create.cshtml"

I resolved it in another way (see my self response below).
Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did to circumvent the problem. I just changed my controller this way:

```
Models.Action act = db.Actions.Find(configurationfile.ActionId);
ModelState.Clear();
configurationfile.Action = act;

TryValidateModel(configurationfile);
```

And after that, the validation was Ok. A bit hacky (and another possible hit on the DB), but at least, I can keep going.