# C# MVC HttpPost Failed – ViewModel ModelState Issue (The parameter conversion from type 'System.String'...)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

This issue occurs when the form is submitted, triggering a HttpPost back to the Controller.  The ViewModel is partially populated, however the primary entity (“StockItem”) is empty.  The ModelState has the following error:

`[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'RaRApps.Domain.Entities.StockItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}`

Here’s some background:

This is the “StockItem” object definition.  It includes relationships with 4 other objects (one of which is referenced 3 times):

```
public class StockItem  
{  
    public int id { get; set; }  
    public string title { get; set; }  

    public virtual StockType stockType {get;set;}  
    public virtual Category category {get;set;}  
    public virtual Supplier supplier {get;set;}  
    public virtual Unit purchUnit { get; set; }  
    public virtual Unit countUnit { get; set; }  
    public virtual Unit useUnit { get; set; }  
}
```

The Context is setup as follows, with relationships explicitly defined:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext  
{  
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }  


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
    {  
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("categories");  
        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().ToTable("stock_items");  
        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().ToTable("suppliers");  
        modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>().ToTable("units");  

        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasRequired(s => s.purchUnit)  
            .WithMany(u => u.purchaseStockItems)  
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("purch_unit_id"));  

        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasRequired(s => s.countUnit)  
            .WithMany(u => u.countStockItems)  
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("count_unit_id"));  

        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasRequired(s => s.useUnit)  
            .WithMany(u => u.useStockItems)  
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("use_unit_id"));  

        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasRequired(s => s.supplier)  
            .WithMany(u => u.stockItems)  
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("supplier_id"));  

        modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasRequired(c => c.category)  
            .WithMany(s => s.stockItems)  
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("category_id"));  

    }  
}
```

A ViewModel is used to pass:
+ The “StockItem” Object
+ values for DropDownLists
+ select DropDownList values

```
public class EditStockItemModel  
{  
    public StockItem stockItem { get; set; }  

    public SelectList supplierList { get; set; }  
    public int selectedSupplier { get; set; }  

    public SelectList categoryList { get; set; }  
    public int selectedCategory { get; set; }  

    public SelectList purchUnitList { get; set; }  
    public int selectedPurchUnit { get; set; }  

    public SelectList countUnitList { get; set; }  
    public int selectedCountUnit { get; set; }  

    public SelectList useUnitList { get; set; }  
    public int selectedUseUnit { get; set; }  
}
```

The “StockItem” Controller populates the ViewModel before calling the “Edit” View

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int stockItem_id)  
    {  
        StockItem Item = this.stockItemRepo.SiteStockItems().FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == stockItem_id);  
        EditStockItemModel model = new EditStockItemModel();  

        model.stockItem = Item;  
        model.selectedCategory = Item.category.id;  
        model.selectedSupplier = Item.supplier.id;  
        model.selectedPurchUnit = Item.purchUnit.id;  
        model.selectedCountUnit = Item.countUnit.id;  
        model.selectedUseUnit = Item.useUnit.id;  

        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())  
        {  
            kernel.Bind<ICategoryRepository>().To<EFCategoryRepository>();  
            model.categoryList = new SelectList(kernel.Get<ICategoryRepository>().SiteStockCategories(site_id).Where(s => s.active == 1), "id", "title");  

            kernel.Bind<ISupplierRepository>().To<EFSupplierRepository>();  
            model.supplierList = new SelectList(kernel.Get<ISupplierRepository>().SiteSuppliers(site_id).Where(s => s.active == 1), "id", "title");  

            kernel.Bind<IUnitRepository>().To<EFUnitRepository>();  
            model.purchUnitList = new SelectList(kernel.Get<IUnitRepository>().SiteUnits(site_id).Where(u => u.active == 1), "id", "title");  
            model.countUnitList = new SelectList(kernel.Get<IUnitRepository>().SiteUnits(site_id).Where(u => u.active == 1), "id", "title");  
            model.useUnitList = new SelectList(kernel.Get<IUnitRepository>().SiteUnits(site_id).Where(u => u.active == 1), "id", "title");  
        }  

        return View(model);  
    }
```

The ViewModel is passed back to the “StockItem” Controller when the View Form is submitted.  However, the “StockItem” object is empty.  The ModelState shows an error suggesting that the “StockItem” cannot be generated.

```
    [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult Edit(EditStockItemModel model)  
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  
        {  
            stockItemRepo.SaveStockItem(model.stockItem, model.selectedCategory, model.selectedSupplier, model.selectedPurchUnit, model.selectedCountUnit, model.selectedUseUnit);  
        }  
        return RedirectToAction("List");  
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to correct this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the View Code, as requested.  I changed the SelectLists to be sourced from the ViewBag to simplify the model being posted.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>


    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.stockItem, new { id = "hdnID"})

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stockItem.title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.stockItem.title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.stockItem.title)
    </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stockItem.category)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCategory, (SelectList)ViewBag.categoryList)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stockItem.supplier)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedSupplier, (SelectList)ViewBag.supplierList)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stockItem.purchUnit)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedPurchUnit, (SelectList)ViewBag.purchUnitList)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stockItem.countUnit)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCountUnit, (SelectList)ViewBag.countUnitList)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.stockItem.useUnit)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedUseUnit, (SelectList)ViewBag.useUnitList)
            </div>


    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Could you add your View markup for the GET Edit method?

Comment: Seems the HttpPost creates a new instance of the ViewModel.  I added elements for some of the fields that are not required for this view, just in case they were required for creating the new ViewModel, but it didn't help :-(

Comment: Also tried moving the SelectLists from the ViewModel to the ViewBag to reduce the complexity of the ViewModel.  But this didn't help either :-(

Comment: I encountered a similar error due to using a `reserve word`. So, if the problem is caused from a similar issue, you might have a look at my answer on [The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'T' failed because no type converter can convert between these types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406094/the-parameter-conversion-from-type-system-string-to-type-t-failed-because-no/35025214#35025214). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue!  The View had a small mistake.  The following tag didn't have the field specified.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.stockItem, new { id = "hdnID"})
```

It works when I include the field, as follows:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.stockItem.id, new { id = "hdnID"})
```

Comment: I have the same problem too. If i choose model.stockitem.id it works fine when stockitem.id is required field. what if i have nullable stockitem then it does not work

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

I found the issue! The View had a small mistake. The following tag didn't have the field specified.

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.stockItem, new { id = "hdnID"})
It works when I include the field, as follows:

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.stockItem.id, new { id = "hdnID"})

Its Magic